# How does 'unique' work in the TotallyLazy library

Tags: java, objective-c, totallylazy

How can I use the 'unique' method in the TotallyLazy library for Java and Objective-C?

I have the following code, but I cannot complete it because I'm not sure how the Callable1 instance passed into 'unique' should be composed. Here's what I have so far:

```
        seq
        .sort(new Comparator<T>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(
                final T pt1,
                final T pt2
            ) {
                return pt1.compareTo(pt2);
            }
        })
        .unique(new Callable1<T,T>() {
            @Override
            public T call(final T pt) throws Exception {
                final int result = pt.compareTo(..?);
                return result != 0;
            }});
```

As you can see, I can sort successfully, but when it comes to "result = ..." in the 'unique' call, what should I put?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly for sorting you should probably use one of the provided Comparators:

```
seq.sort(Comparators.<T>ascending());
```

Then you could just `unique` with no arguments if uniqueness is based on equality of T as a whole. The overload for `unique` allows one to get a unique sequence based on some property of `T`.

For example if you had a `Sequence<User>` you could say I want them to be unique based on their `firstName` field:

```
class User { 
    String firstName, lastName; 
    User(...){...} // Constructor
}

sequence(new User("Chris", "Nash")).unique(user -> user.firstName)
```

TotallyLazy has extensive Tests that document the features but the first place to start would always be the [SequenceTest](https://code.google.com/p/totallylazy/source/browse/test/com/googlecode/totallylazy/SequenceTest.java) or have a look in the whole [test package](https://code.google.com/p/totallylazy/source/browse/#hg%2Ftest%2Fcom%2Fgooglecode%2Ftotallylazy) for more examples.